# Is it possible to create a for loop in creating functions?

Tags: javascript, loops

Is it possible to to create a for loop in creating functions(and etc)? Only to reduce hard coding, because i have many values in the array. i have here my code and it doesn't work.

```js
var obj=["backupF31","backupF32","backupF33","backupF34","backupF35"];

for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
  function obj[i] ()
  { 
  var data = {};
            $.ajax({type: 'POST', data: JSON.stringify(data), contentType: 'application/json', 
       url: '/legone/survey/'+obj[i]+'',      
                    success: function(data) {   
                        }
                    });
 alert("Sucessful backup on "+obj[i]+");
  }
}
```

From the code above, i only want to insert the values of the array in the obj[i] Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve here but if you wanted to create a list of functions that are called afterwards, this snippet might help you to start:

```js
var obj=["backupF31","backupF32","backupF33","backupF34","backupF35"];

var functions = obj.map(function(key) {
  return function(data) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      data: JSON.stringify(data),
      contentType: 'application/json',
      url: '/legone/survey/'+key+'',
      success: function(response) {
        data[key] = response
      }
    });
    alert("Sucessful backup on "+obj[i]+");
  }
}

var data = {};
functions.forEach(function(f) {
  f(data);
});
```

If this is not what you wanted, please comment :)

Answer (score 1):

This might be one way of doing what you want to do:

```
function doThing(message)
{ 
    var data = {};
    $.ajax({type: 'POST', data: JSON.stringify(data), contentType: 'application/json', 
                url: '/legone/survey/'+message+'',                      
                success: function(data) {   
                    }
                });
    alert("Successful backup on "+message+".");
}

var obj=[doThing.bind(null, "backupF31"), doThing.bind(null, "backupF32"), 
         doThing.bind(null, "backupF33"), doThing.bind(null, "backupF34"),
         doThing.bind(null, "backupF35")];

for (var thisObj of obj) {
    thisObj();
}
```

[`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) creates a function call with pre-defined arguments, so you can capture the different arguments when creating your array of function pointers.